# Logarithmical equation with addition of powers

Tags: logarithms

I just wonder how to solve the equation:
$$ 3^x + 3 \times 9^x = 1200 $$

Mi first idea was to replace $ 9^x $ with $ 3^{2x} $. Then I can mutliply the powers:
$$ 3^x + 3^{2x+1}= 1200 $$ 
But how to go on?

Comment: $9^x=(3^x)^2$. Think of quadratic equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substitute: $$z=3^x \implies z+3*z^2=1200$$